# Find matrix rank depending on two parameters with entries in $\mathbb{Z/7Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

How do find the rank of the given matrix depending on parameters $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_{7}$?

$$ A\in Mat_{3,4}(\mathbb{Z}_{7}), A=\begin{pmatrix} \overline{2} &b  &\overline{1}  &\overline{3} \\  \overline{-3} &\overline{3} b & \overline{2} a& \overline{0}\\   a & \overline{4} -a & \overline{-3} &\overline{1} +\overline{2} b \end{pmatrix}$$

I have found matrix rank by reducing matrix to echelon form, but there were no parameters involved in those questions, even more, two. I've spent days trying to figure out a solution by different methods (e.g by changing (-3) to 4 [they both give the same reminder when divided with 7] and then performed row operations, but it just did not worked out since i did not manage to reduce “a” to 0 etc. Then I started wondering whether I should just start by letting a/b equal to zero and watch different cases separately and reduce them to a desired form separately? I appreciate your help and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some initial steps to get you started. For convenience, I'm omitting the bars.

Since we're only looking for the rank of this matrix, we can also apply *column operations*.
$$
\pmatrix{2 &b  &{1}  &{3} \\  
{-3} &{3} b & {2} a& {0}\\   
a & {4} -a & {-3} &{1} +{2} b} \leadsto\\
\pmatrix{1 &4b  &4  &5 \\  
{-3} &{3} b & {2} a& {0}\\   
a & {4} -a & {-3} &{1} +{2} b} \leadsto\\
\pmatrix{1 &4b  &4  &5 \\  
0 & b & {2}a-2& 1\\   
a & {4} -a & {-3} &{1} +{2} b} \leadsto\\
\pmatrix{1 &4b  &4  &5 \\  
0 & b & {2}a-2& 1\\   
0 & {4} -a-4ab & -3-4a &2 +{2} b} \leadsto\\
\pmatrix{1 &5  &4  &4b \\  
0 & 1 & {2}a-2& b\\   
0 & 2+2b & -3-4a &4-a-4ab}.\phantom{\leadsto}
$$
The first three steps were row operation, and the last was a permutation of the columns. Perhaps you can take it from here.

Comment: I just gave another (rigorous) answer (the second one) using factorizations that alleviate a little the burden of calculations mod. 7...

Answer (score 0):

In fact, in such cases, when you have spent days on a question as is the case, consider (computed-assisted) "brute force", i.e., build a program that browses all cases, which are not that numerous ($7^2=49$ such matrices).

[All right, it's not considered as a proof]

See below a rather simple (Matlab) program which does the job and finds a **single case** where rank$(A)<3$ for

$$a=4 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ b=5$$

giving matrix :

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&5&1&3\\4&1&1&0\\4&0&4&4\end{pmatrix}$$

More precisely, in this case, rank(A)=$2$ because the $2 \times 2$ upper left block has determinant $2 * 1 - 4 *5 = 3 \ \text{mod} \ 7 \ \ne 0$.

> ```
>  for a=0:6
>     for b=0:6 
>        M=[2,b,1,3;
>          -3,3*b,2*a,0;
>           a,(4-a),-3,(1+2*b)];
>        D=[det(M(:,[2,3,4]),det(M(:,1,3,4)),det(M(:,1,2,4),det(M:,[1,2,3])];
>        D=mod(round(D),7);
>        if not(any(D));% if all 3x3 det. are zeros
>           [a,b]
>        end;
>     end;
>  end;
> ```

Comment: In fact, I just found a (theoretical) proof. I am going to write it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rigorous answer.

I thought at first to group it with the previous one, but its nature is so different that I prefer to write a separate answer.

I will take the same conventions as Ben Grossmann : no overbars, and sign $\leadsto$ meaning "rank-equivalent" (having the same ranks depending in the same way on the values of $a$ and $b$).

Starting from
Preliminary remark: as we can extract from

$$A=\pmatrix{2 &b  &1  &3 \\  
-3 &3 b & 2a& 0\\   
a & (4-a) & -3 &(1+2b)},\tag{1}$$

a submatrix $\pmatrix{2  &3 \\  
-3& 0}$ with determinant $5 \ne 0$, rank$(A) \ge 2$.

We are going to perform on $A$ different row (R) or column (C) operations that do not change the rank of the matrix:

As row number two, denoted $R_2$, can be written (with operations mod. $7$) :

$\pmatrix{4 &-4b  &2a  &0}$, in which we can factorize $2$ giving $\pmatrix{2 &-2b  &a  &0}$ ; subtracting this new row at the same time to row $R_1$, gives

$$\leadsto \ \ A':=\pmatrix{0 &3b  &(1-a)  &3 \\  
2 & -2b & a& 0\\   
a & (4-a) & -3 &(1+2b)}\tag{2}$$

Let us now consider $C_1$ (column 1) written under the form (always with the rules mod. 7):

$$\leadsto \ \ \pmatrix{0 &3b  &(1-a)  &3 \\  
2 & -2b & a& 0\\   
\color{red}{-6}a & (4-a) & -3 &(1+2b)}\tag{3}$$

We can factorize $2$, this time in column 1, and simultaneously, as we have done before when working on rows, subtract this new column 1 to column 3, yielding:

$$ \leadsto \ \ A''':=\pmatrix{0 &3b  &(1-a)  &3 \\  
1 & -2b & (a-1)& 0\\   
-3a & (4-a) & -3(a-1) &(1+2b)}\tag{4}$$

If $a-1 \ne 0$ (we will come back on this hypothesis later), we can factorize it, and matrix $A'''$ is rank-equivalent to:

$$ \leadsto  \ \ \ A'''':=\pmatrix{0 &3b  &1  &3 \\  
1 & -2b & -1& 0\\   
-3a & (4-a) & -3 &(1+2b)}\tag{5}$$

As a consequence, the rank of $A''''$ (and therefore the rank of $A$) is exactly equal to $2$ if and only if the four $3 \times 3$ determinants that one can extract from $A''''$ are all equal to $0$.

This gives the following system

$$\begin{cases}D_1&=&4a-4b-2-2b^2&=&0& \ (A)\\
D_2&=&-2a-2b-10&=&0& \ (B)\\
D_3&=&-3a-3b-18ab-6b^2&=&0& \ (C)\\
D_4&=&-a+2b+3ab+4&=&0& \ (D)\end{cases}$$

where $D_k$ is the determinant of the submatrix of $A''''$ obtained by suppressing the $k$th column.

The previous system can be simplified into:

$$\begin{cases}2a-2b-1-b^2&=&0& \ (A)\\
-a-b-5&=&0& \ (B)\\
-a-b-6ab-2b^2&=&0& \ (C)\\
-a+2b+4+3ab&=&0& \ (D)\end{cases}$$

Out of this system, one is able to build a system of 2 linear equations with two unknowns ; the first of these equations is (B), the second one being obtained by combination of the other equations $-3 \times (A)+(C)+2 \times (D)$.

This gives finally

$$a=4, \  \ b=5$$

But we have left a special case $a=1$ to be treated apart. Let us establish that this case cannot happen.

If we had not simplified (4) into (5), we would have had, by taking $a=1$ in (4):

$$A'''=\pmatrix{0 &3b  &0  &3 \\  
1 & -2b & 0 & 0\\   
-3 & 3 & 0 &(1+2b)}\tag{4}$$

Three of the four determinants extracted from this matrix are evidently $0$ but one of them (obtained by removing the third column) has value $b^2+2$.

But quadratic equation $b^2+2=0$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Z_7}$ ($-2$ is not a quadratic residue in this field), ruling out the possibility for $a$ to be equal to $1$. $\square$

Comment: Any comment ?...